# How to deal with inline PHP foreign language characters?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, web

I'm having a problem with my php web app. It is in Portuguese, and while all the data into and from the database inputs and outputs fine, and all the inline html outputs fine, the php strings don't.

For example:

If I have a function that outputs the last update of the database entry:

```
$output .= 'Última atualização: ' . $date . '.';
```

When php echoes the above all the accented characters will be garbled. If the same are inline in the HTML or from the database they display normally.

Note: I have declared my encoding as `utf-8` both in the html header and in the php script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual PHP file (which is just a text file) also has to have the respective encoding.

And it doesn't work to just add the correct header. You have to open the file, check if the encoding is utf8, if not, cut everything, change the encoding to utf8 and paste everything back. It doesn't work, if you just change the encoding and save the file, unless your text editor has such a function of course!

Comment: I use this method, but i wonder, how does the php interpreter know that the .php file is utf-8 encoded?  thanks

Comment: This did the trick! Although I will have to go through the entire site and re-enter all the special characters (Dreamweaver garbled them all at once). Thanks!

Comment: @IssacharWEB Do NOT use Dreamweaver! To change the encoding of your files, use for example Notepad 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the .php file to UTF-8. This can be done in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your browser is set to UTF-8 also. I just ran your above statement:

```
$output = 'Última atualização: ' . now();
echo $output;
```

and it looks fine.

If it still doesn't solve your problem, add some more code to get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: This has nothing to do with browser encoding.

Comment: If I don't declare the encoding in the header and in the php file, all the strings output fine, but the database info does not. I don't know if my keyboard makes a difference (I use Mac OSX Lion with the regular English Keyboard). Here is the function mentioned above:

Comment: @markus, you're actually wrong. Browser encoding also affects how the page is displayed. Run my code above and then go and change browser encoding settings to ISO-8859-1 and the string is displayed differently. I wasn't saying that's the problem. I was merely suggesting that display of those characters is affected by the current browser encoding just as much as the content encoding of the page

Comment: To add to above, when I change my Chrome's encoding, the above code produces: Ãšltima atualizaÃ§Ã£o: 1321466936

Comment: @IssacharWEB, what collation are you using on the char data in the database that you are displaying?

Comment: @AlexeyGerasimov utf8_general_ci - but see above, it was the actual php file's encoding that was the problem. I somehow had no idea that there was that setting as well.

Comment: @AlexeyGerasimov I did not say that browser encoding can't have an influence but the presented problem was clearly not connected to this.

Comment: @markus, I really don't want to get in the back-and-forth. The solution in this case happened to be the actual php file encoding and I will give you credit for that. However, my recommendation to check browser encoding is a valid suggestion for others to be aware of. You can have php file encoded in UTF-8 and the $output encoded in UTF-8 but when you spit it out to the browser set to ISO-8859-1, it will look funny. My answer might not have been what solved this particular issue but I certainly wouldn't jump to giving it -1 without trying and verifying.

Comment: What I ment is that the browser is designed to recognize encoding. You should not need to change any settings there. So if the OP tests in any modern browser with default settings (which is the normal case for a development environment) then the problem won't be with the browser encoding. So let's say the chance that this would solve the problem was really marginal.